# Searching for Addresses using Skobbler multistep search

Tags: android, geocoding, openstreetmap, skmaps

I have a problem in programming multistep search correctly as it is described here ["How to" for the Android SDK - Offline geocoding](http://developer.skobbler.de/getting-started/android#sec019). Searching step by step from country to housenumber I receive a `List` of `SKSearchResult`. In every result have a parentList on every level. But on housenumber level(`SK_LIST_LEVEL_HOUSENUMBER`)something is corrupt. All parents are lost at this level.

Searching for “Germany” on country level shows this result:

```
SKSearchResult [id=11711160340447248, type=COUNTRY, name=Deutschland, parentsList=[], category=SKPOI_CATEGORY_UNKNOWN, mainCategory=null, location=[10.423439979553223,51.08341979980469], offlinePackageCode=DE]
```

Searching for “Berlin” on city level shows these results:

```
SKSearchResult [id=80911995709853584, type=CITY, name=Berlin, parentsList=[SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1074716573, parentType=COUNTRY, parentName=Deutschland]], category=SKPOI_CATEGORY_UNKNOWN, mainCategory=null, location=[13.3888578414917,52.51703643798828], offlinePackageCode=DE]
SKSearchResult [id=15911939014706960, type=CITY, name=Bernau bei Berlin, parentsList=[SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1074716573, parentType=STATE, parentName=Brandenburg], SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1074716573, parentType=COUNTRY, parentName=Deutschland]], category=SKPOI_CATEGORY_UNKNOWN, mainCategory=null, location=[13.588103294372559,52.67873001098633], offlinePackageCode=DE]
SKSearchResult [id=19123745631193744, type=CITY, name=Neuenhagen bei Berlin, parentsList=[SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1074716573, parentType=STATE, parentName=Brandenburg], SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1074716573, parentType=COUNTRY, parentName=Deutschland]], category=SKPOI_CATEGORY_UNKNOWN, mainCategory=null, location=[13.688921928405762,52.52616882324219], offlinePackageCode=DE]
```

Searching for “Unter den Linden” on street level with “Berlin”s ID as parentID shows these results:

```
SKSearchResult [id=179887248, type=STREET, name=Unter den Linden, parentsList=[SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1628087140, parentType=CITY_SECTOR, parentName=Mitte], SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1628087140, parentType=CITY, parentName=Berlin], SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1628087140, parentType=COUNTRY, parentName=Deutschland]], category=SKPOI_CATEGORY_UNKNOWN, mainCategory=null, location=[13.393696784973145,52.51726531982422], offlinePackageCode=DE]
SKSearchResult [id=179153424, type=STREET, name=Unter den Rüstern, parentsList=[SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1728731020, parentType=CITY_SECTOR, parentName=Steglitz], SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1728731020, parentType=CITY, parentName=Berlin], SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1728731020, parentType=COUNTRY, parentName=Deutschland]], category=SKPOI_CATEGORY_UNKNOWN, mainCategory=null, location=[13.339591026306152,52.44643020629883], offlinePackageCode=DE]
SKSearchResult [id=179089296, type=STREET, name=Unter den Eichen, parentsList=[SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1728731020, parentType=CITY, parentName=Erkner], SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1728731020, parentType=STATE, parentName=Brandenburg], SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1728731020, parentType=COUNTRY, parentName=Deutschland]], category=SKPOI_CATEGORY_UNKNOWN, mainCategory=null, location=[13.75512981414795,52.43838119506836], offlinePackageCode=DE]
```

Searching for “2” on houseumber level with “Unter den Linden”s ID as parentID shows these results:

```
SKSearchResult [id=0, type=POINT, name=2, parentsList=[], category=SKPOI_CATEGORY_UNKNOWN, mainCategory=null, location=[13.397054672241211,52.51759719848633], offlinePackageCode=DE]
SKSearchResult [id=0, type=POINT, name=21, parentsList=[], category=SKPOI_CATEGORY_UNKNOWN, mainCategory=null, location=[13.393257141113281,52.51721954345703], offlinePackageCode=DE]
SKSearchResult [id=0, type=POINT, name=23, parentsList=[], category=SKPOI_CATEGORY_UNKNOWN, mainCategory=null, location=[13.392806053161621,52.517127990722656], offlinePackageCode=DE]
```

As you can see at this last level(housenumber) only results of type `POINT` are found. There are no results of type `HOUSE_NUMBER`. Furthermore information is lost because in the last results there is an empty `parentList=[]`

May this be a bug in Skobbler SDK? Or do I maybe misuse the SDK?

Comment: we're checking with our developers this issue

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was much easier to implement an outside source for Geocoding a search. Nominatim is an open source geocoding engine that allows integration with Skobbler and online searching. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

The API can be found here: https://github.com/jeremiehuchet/nominatim-java-api

Comment: As it stands, this is more of a comment than an answer. Can you perhaps show *how* you'd integrate an outside source?